# How to divide long text into columns, as in newspapers?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

Is there any framework support for this, or should I just write my own code for this?

Reading long lines of text is difficult and causes fatigue. Readable text should consist of short lines. The problem is when in my application I have large horizontal space to cover with text.

In good application the presentation layer should be independent from data layer, which is the text in this case. So I need multi-column text layout, but dividing text into columns must be done by the program, it cannot be hardcoded.

In HTML/CSS3 it's easy. Is there some support for it in XAML?

If there isn't, do you know some libraries capable of displaying multi-column layout?

The best would be if the control could decide whether to use multiple columns. If the rectangle is wider than taller - then yes. If it's taller than wider - then no.

Comment: when you say text do you mean a string that you simply want to divide?

Comment: The input is a string. Read from string resources. But I want columns as result. Exactly as in `FlowDocument`, but well, in UWP app too. I have a long description, it's unreadable when presented screen-wide. I'm very surprised `FlowDocument` is unavailable in UWP. I found no similar control. There is `RichTextBlock`, but it doesn't seem to have columns support. Like Microsoft assumed that UWP will be used only with small screens, which is not very "universal".

Answer (score 1):

You must work with DocumentViewer, a WPF control specialized to render documents. Read this article : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please add some example code, answers should stand on their own without being rendered useless if a link breaks

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I just added an example. It's pretty easy when you know where to look. I needed to find out where the `Paragraph` element fits, and which `UIElemet` has the capability of using columns and contain paragraphs. I figured `FlowDocument` does. And it needs to be contained in `FlowDocumentPageViewer`. Then I just needed to hide the controls and this is it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all, your answers allowed me to quickly produce a basic WPF code example:

```
<Window x:Class="TextFlow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextFlow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Black" Foreground="Gray">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="NoPageControls" TargetType="{x:Type FlowDocumentPageViewer}">
            <AdornerDecorator>
                <DocumentPageView FlowDocumentPageViewer.IsMasterPage="True" />
            </AdornerDecorator>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <FlowDocumentPageViewer Template="{StaticResource NoPageControls}">
            <FlowDocument ColumnWidth="200" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="10">
                <Paragraph>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae purus pellentesque, ultricies magna a, egestas nisl. Quisque eu risus quis elit posuere imperdiet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla sagittis, felis at luctus tempus, metus dolor ultricies mi, vitae aliquet justo libero non arcu. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas luctus rutrum lorem non congue. Sed vitae blandit felis. Nullam eu leo non dui vulputate tincidunt id eu odio. Etiam risus velit, consequat vel tortor in, condimentum vestibulum est. Sed maximus elementum erat nec fermentum.
                </Paragraph>
                <Paragraph>
                    Donec nec ex dignissim, ornare arcu eu, fermentum ipsum. Cras ullamcorper blandit quam, in pulvinar justo sodales quis. Vivamus sed tincidunt augue, nec convallis lorem. Phasellus lobortis nibh sem, sit amet suscipit tellus dapibus at. Aliquam arcu tellus, aliquet at cursus sodales, ornare a sem. Morbi sollicitudin orci et hendrerit ullamcorper. In non faucibus risus. Morbi eget metus pharetra quam consequat pretium quis ac enim. Integer scelerisque elit malesuada pharetra condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut at consectetur erat. Phasellus pulvinar consequat erat quis placerat. Cras tortor mi, tempor ultricies sodales at, faucibus quis lacus. Morbi semper vestibulum odio eget tempor. Praesent at mollis erat. Praesent sollicitudin nulla sit amet magna fermentum porta.
                </Paragraph>
                <Paragraph>
                    Proin tincidunt ex interdum, sodales leo non, fringilla tellus. Vestibulum eget posuere purus, et aliquam arcu. Sed ac dolor ullamcorper, rutrum sapien sit amet, convallis enim. Mauris a faucibus augue. Morbi porta nunc ac ligula suscipit consequat. Curabitur in interdum elit. Pellentesque tempor tempor tellus, ut bibendum elit consequat vitae. Fusce commodo ac nunc ut pretium. Vestibulum ut vulputate est. Nullam pharetra ornare elementum. Nullam eros nunc, tincidunt at porta sit amet, rutrum in mauris. Vivamus id ante sit amet velit pulvinar interdum. Cras efficitur egestas nunc id tempor. Vivamus eu enim vitae lorem molestie tincidunt nec et ex. Integer nec turpis nisi.
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentPageViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Yes, some manual processing is still necessary, but it's perfectly good when I just want to display some localized descriptions in a readable manner.

Some automatics (like determining if the columns are needed or how wide should they be) could be easily added to this, but I'll leave the example as easy as possible. The control template must be applied in order to hide page controls. If the text is bigger and doesn't fit in one page - you just leave original template alone.

**This is unfortunately unavailable in UWP. Is it?**

So, we need to go deeper. No help from UWP, fine, let's make a control which would do at least what WPF control did, right?

**Without further ado - `ReadableBlock` control:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents;

namespace ReadableBlockDemo.Controls {
    public sealed class ReadableBlock : ContentControl {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ReadableBlock), null);

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextAlignmentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TextAlignment", typeof(TextAlignment), typeof(ReadableBlock), new PropertyMetadata(TextAlignment.Left));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(int), typeof(ReadableBlock), new PropertyMetadata(1));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnSpacingProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnSpacing", typeof(double), typeof(ReadableBlock), new PropertyMetadata(10d));

        public string Text {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public TextAlignment TextAlignment {
            get { return (TextAlignment)GetValue(TextAlignmentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextAlignmentProperty, value); }
        }

        public int Columns {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, (int)value); }
        }

        public double ColumnSpacing {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ColumnSpacingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ColumnSpacingProperty, (double)value); }
        }

        public new string Content {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
            set { base.Content = null; SetValue(ContentProperty, Text = (string)value); RenderText(); }
        }

        private StackPanel Container => base.Content as StackPanel;

        private double AvailableWidth;

        private double AvailableHeight;

        private TextBlock[] Blocks;

        private double ColumnWidth;

        private bool IsTextRenderingAvailable;

        public ReadableBlock() {
            Loaded += ReadableBlock_Loaded;
        }

        private void ReadableBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            LayoutUpdated += ReadableBlock_LayoutUpdated;
            InvalidateArrange();
        }

        private void ReadableBlock_LayoutUpdated(object sender, object e) {
            if (ActualWidth != AvailableWidth || ActualHeight != AvailableHeight) OnAvailableSizeChanged();
        }

        private void OnAvailableSizeChanged() {
            IsTextRenderingAvailable = true;
            AvailableWidth = ActualWidth;
            AvailableHeight = ActualHeight;
            double n = Columns;
            double s = ColumnSpacing;
            ColumnWidth = (AvailableWidth - ((n - 1d) * s)) / n;
            if (Blocks == null) CreateColumns();
            RenderText();
        }

        private void CreateColumns() {
            var container = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
            var columns = Columns;
            var spacing = ColumnSpacing;
            var blocks = new List<TextBlock>();
            TextBlock block;
            for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
                blocks.Add(block = new TextBlock { TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap, TextAlignment = TextAlignment, Width = ColumnWidth, Height = AvailableHeight });
                if (i > 0) block.Margin = new Thickness(spacing, 0, 0, 0);
                container.Children.Add(block);
            }
            base.Content = container;
            Blocks = blocks.ToArray();
        }

        private int GetSplitOffset(string text) {
            var m = new TextBlock { FontFamily = FontFamily, FontSize = FontSize, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap, TextAlignment = TextAlignment };
            m.Text = text;
            m.Measure(new Size(ColumnWidth, double.PositiveInfinity));
            if (m.DesiredSize.Height < AvailableHeight) return -1;
            var p = m.ContentStart;
            var r = p.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            for (int i = 0, l = text.Length; i < l && r.Bottom < AvailableHeight; i++) {
                p = p.GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                r = p.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            }
            return p.Offset - 2;
        }

        private bool SetBlock(int i, string text) {
            if (i >= Blocks.Length) return false;
            var block = Blocks[i];
            block.Width = ColumnWidth;
            block.Height = AvailableHeight;
            block.Text = text;
            return true;
        }

        private void RenderText() {
            if (!IsTextRenderingAvailable || Text == null) return;
            int i = 0, splitOffset = 0, n = Blocks.Length;
            string text = Text;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) Blocks[i].Text = "";
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                splitOffset = GetSplitOffset(text);
                if (splitOffset > 0) {
                    if (!SetBlock(i, text.Substring(0, splitOffset))) return;
                    if (!SetBlock(i + 1, text = text.Substring(splitOffset))) return;
                }
                else {
                    SetBlock(i, text);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And of some XAML to test it:

```
<Page
    x:Class="ReadableBlockDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ReadableBlockDemo"
    xmlns:Controls="using:ReadableBlockDemo.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="#444"
    Foreground="Gray"
    >
    <Grid>
        <Controls:ReadableBlock Columns="4" ColumnSpacing="25" TextAlignment="Justify" Margin="25">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tempor ipsum massa, ac lacinia libero sagittis lobortis. Donec pretium ex quis massa eleifend dignissim. Maecenas quis est odio. Proin facilisis mollis purus, vitae dapibus lacus interdum ac. Sed molestie id lorem vel volutpat. Ut vitae quam sem. Pellentesque convallis elementum ipsum commodo porttitor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed porta eros. Pellentesque eget dolor euismod, fermentum orci vitae, ullamcorper mauris. Aliquam tempus hendrerit sollicitudin. Nunc sed erat quis ligula dictum convallis. Mauris eget finibus odio. Aenean sagittis congue purus, at elementum mi rhoncus ut. Suspendisse hendrerit dictum eleifend. Nullam scelerisque, eros ac euismod semper, velit sapien tincidunt purus, a tempus enim ante ut turpis. In vehicula arcu vitae nunc eleifend, id porta felis consequat.
            Praesent vel tincidunt dui. Ut ut turpis lacus. Nullam accumsan laoreet elit eu suscipit. Cras aliquet pellentesque fringilla. Nullam ut consectetur nisi, non tristique quam. Suspendisse vitae gravida ipsum. Fusce ac enim non arcu rutrum sollicitudin. Aliquam in odio id tellus venenatis egestas et quis sapien. Etiam scelerisque ultrices tellus, quis dignissim leo gravida id.
            Etiam ut elit tortor. Fusce fringilla accumsan urna eu viverra. Nunc porttitor lorem vitae magna ultrices lacinia. Etiam posuere sed dui nec gravida. Aenean fermentum turpis vehicula, blandit arcu id, mollis nulla. Praesent laoreet tellus vitae lectus consequat interdum. Duis interdum feugiat interdum.
            Nam ut maximus est. Vestibulum sagittis eros ut diam ultrices eleifend. Praesent purus quam, luctus quis arcu at, interdum dapibus leo. Vivamus eget massa in leo malesuada egestas quis eget ipsum. Etiam consequat ullamcorper est, in ultricies lacus lobortis commodo. Nullam feugiat libero vitae convallis pellentesque. Pellentesque vitae tristique massa. In sollicitudin pretium nisl sit amet dignissim. Curabitur sodales fringilla ex, sit amet gravida lacus dignissim tempus. Aenean libero lectus, viverra eu eros in, pellentesque accumsan elit. Proin porttitor metus nulla, sit amet vulputate mauris finibus ut. Phasellus viverra risus sapien, eget sodales neque rhoncus vel. Nam quis ullamcorper nulla.
            Duis sed ante dignissim, consequat orci in, iaculis nisi. Etiam nec interdum magna. Donec pharetra fermentum mi, eu aliquet diam hendrerit eget. Aenean vitae ligula sem. Sed at dignissim lorem. Proin vulputate massa eleifend, sagittis leo sit amet, condimentum mi. Curabitur nec vulputate nibh. Nunc ut dictum sapien. Praesent eu rhoncus lectus. Nullam eu auctor dui. Sed accumsan leo et ligula tempus semper. Suspendisse sed magna ut lectus pharetra malesuada.
            Nullam pretium ligula non elit tempus imperdiet. In convallis a mauris vitae venenatis. Morbi pulvinar placerat ante nec tristique. Sed sodales leo in erat fermentum malesuada. Nullam vel turpis ut nulla tempus faucibus. Fusce dictum odio vel felis fringilla, a iaculis urna ultricies. Sed at mauris dolor. Aenean et vulputate libero, at sollicitudin leo. Morbi pretium gravida turpis ac bibendum. Aliquam lacinia mauris ut ante pharetra accumsan. Ut hendrerit, diam in iaculis egestas, justo magna pulvinar sapien, ut pellentesque purus orci id magna. Morbi egestas vestibulum dui, a ullamcorper turpis. Aenean molestie luctus lacus, vel pellentesque elit tincidunt sit amet. Suspendisse eu cursus enim. In eu libero a ipsum interdum aliquam quis blandit quam.
            Fusce tortor nisi, pretium non dolor vitae, pretium condimentum ex. Cras facilisis odio tortor, et scelerisque quam volutpat non. Nam fermentum, velit in molestie venenatis, odio ante dapibus nulla, sed luctus ex urna sit amet lectus. Donec sit amet eros at nulla tempor venenatis. Cras nec purus porttitor dolor pretium auctor. Mauris sed ligula eget libero egestas tempus quis eu ipsum. Duis fermentum egestas libero. Praesent a mi ut felis facilisis pharetra id vel nulla.
            Aenean dolor leo, placerat ac lobortis ut, tincidunt sit amet ex. Pellentesque at convallis massa. Vivamus fermentum eu augue vel sollicitudin. Donec dictum libero sem, et bibendum ex ultricies eget. Sed eu feugiat odio. Sed eget ex congue, dapibus magna ac, finibus diam. Nunc sollicitudin euismod dictum. Nullam rutrum mauris ut ipsum finibus, et euismod arcu sodales. In pellentesque molestie nunc, eget pellentesque metus varius et. Morbi augue nisl, aliquet eu scelerisque at, dictum eu elit. Quisque id ex quis urna facilisis rutrum nec in risus. Sed lorem justo, tempus at ante quis, cursus ultrices tellus. Donec lacinia varius lacus, vitae molestie velit auctor vitae. Aenean vulputate ullamcorper justo sit amet consectetur. Fusce vel risus mattis augue ultrices molestie. Donec sed rhoncus diam.
            Nulla condimentum cursus massa semper suscipit. Cras non porta diam. Donec sed erat eu lectus vehicula hendrerit. Proin a ex tellus. Morbi aliquet dolor in ante lobortis, consequat aliquam dolor cursus. Sed molestie odio massa, a consectetur turpis pellentesque eget. Maecenas quis pharetra ligula, non rutrum libero. Aenean maximus nibh vel nisl elementum imperdiet. Integer et urna eu velit porttitor eleifend. Nunc et pharetra nisl. Nulla porttitor pellentesque mi. Suspendisse porta a ipsum at interdum.
        </Controls:ReadableBlock>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

OK. No scrolling, no formatting, just basics. Just columns, fixed amount.
Not tested thoroughly, so there may be a bug or two, but it should work fine with the example text.

I think it would be way harder if we allowed formatted text. Or maybe not? Well, this example splits plain strings. `TextBlock` exposes `ContentStart` property, which allows us to get pixel coordinates of a all characters in `TextBlock` - if it's only measured. So we create invisible `TextBlock` - set its width to column width and we search at which index our character falls outside available height.

It beats me how extend this hack to support formatted text, I think the problem would become very "non-trivial" ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use VisualStateManager to adaptively create multiple column view. Let's suppose you want to display your text into three different column then divide your text into three parts and set them as data source for your presentation element in XAML.

```
<Page
x:Class="App7.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AdaptiveLayoutExample"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="650" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="First.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="First.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="Second.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="Second.(Grid.Column)" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="Third.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="Third.(Grid.Column)" Value="2" />

                    <Setter Target="First.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="Second.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="Third.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Narrow">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="First.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="First.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="Second.(Grid.Row)" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="Second.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="Third.(Grid.Row)" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Target="Third.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />

                    <Setter Target="First.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="3" />
                    <Setter Target="Second.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="3" />
                    <Setter Target="Third.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="3" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Name="First" Margin="20,20,0,0">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                    Cras id orci iaculis, aliquet nibh at, dictum lorem. Vivamus 
                    tempus tristique sollicitudin. Etiam interdum et lectus 
                    semper molestie. Phasellus lobortis felis quis risus posuere, 
                    id molestie mi sagittis. Cras odio leo, dictum vitae euismod et, 
                    lacinia non lectus. Integer quis massa velit. Ut at dui 
                    rutrum, venenatis dui a, pretium arcu. Nunc eu urna pulvinar, 
                    condimentum sapien non, consectetur turpis. Pellentesque dapibus, 
                    eros ac rutrum congue, quam dolor rhoncus nunc, ut sagittis nisl 
                    urna in ante. Sed nunc libero, aliquet at elit eget, vulputate 
                    ultrices leo. Aliquam vel sapien varius, blandit dui ac, 
                    fringilla metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                    adipiscing elit. Fusce vehicula odio sit amet tortor lobortis 
                    sagittis. Nullam vestibulum tortor eget risus vulputate, at 
                    semper nunc pharetra. Nullam fringilla dapibus turpis non 
                    vehicula. Proin sollicitudin sapien enim, at interdum risus 
                    cursus quis.
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="Second" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,20,0,0">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    Nam sollicitudin justo quis consequat molestie. Etiam dictum 
                    sodales tellus, ut consectetur magna sodales in. Phasellus viverra 
                    volutpat porttitor. Pellentesque sed condimentum neque. In 
                    ultrices ex ac lacus tincidunt, eget euismod urna cursus. Donec tempor 
                    mauris leo, ac cursus nisl tempus a. Aliquam dignissim eleifend lorem a 
                    facilisis. Praesent tincidunt semper ante non ornare. Cras eleifend 
                    eros et tincidunt auctor. Duis lorem nunc, dictum dignissim est vitae, 
                    luctus dapibus lacus. Donec fringilla ipsum nec diam sagittis, 
                    nec suscipit metus maximus. Aliquam aliquam non ante tincidunt 
                    fringilla. Phasellus auctor, nisl non rutrum imperdiet, arcu
                    purus pretium libero, nec eleifend metus turpis vel ante. Phasellus 
                    sit amet rhoncus lectus.
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="Third" Grid.Row="2" Margin="20,20,0,0">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                    Cras id orci iaculis, aliquet nibh at, dictum lorem. Vivamus 
                    tempus tristique sollicitudin. Etiam interdum et lectus 
                    semper molestie. Phasellus lobortis felis quis risus posuere, 
                    id molestie mi sagittis. Cras odio leo, dictum vitae euismod et, 
                    lacinia non lectus. Integer quis massa velit. Ut at dui 
                    rutrum, venenatis dui a, pretium arcu. Nunc eu urna pulvinar, 
                    condimentum sapien non, consectetur turpis. Pellentesque dapibus, 
                    eros ac rutrum congue, quam dolor rhoncus nunc, ut sagittis nisl 
                    urna in ante. Sed nunc libero, aliquet at elit eget, vulputate 
                    ultrices leo. Aliquam vel sapien varius, blandit dui ac, 
                    fringilla metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                    adipiscing elit. Fusce vehicula odio sit amet tortor lobortis 
                    sagittis. Nullam vestibulum tortor eget risus vulputate, at 
                    semper nunc pharetra. Nullam fringilla dapibus turpis non 
                    vehicula. Proin sollicitudin sapien enim, at interdum risus 
                    cursus quis.
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

When the application window has width less than 650 it sets the the stack panel below of another, therefore you have single column view. When width gets greater than 650 it separate them into three columns.

Comment: That's definitely a part of it - we get different layout depending on space available. But you just hardcoded text division. If the text is read from application resources, its length is unknown. I think there's no way other then making custom ContentControl which measures available space, then creates grid and splits the text into columns.

Comment: @Harry You can subscribe to Window.Current.SizeChanged event and determine the width of the current window. According to that determine how many columns you need to display your text and then split the text into same number of multiple strings and assign those strings as data source to your xaml elements. In your xaml make the number of columns should be the maximum columns that you want to support. By this way you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Determining number of columns is not the hard part here. The hard part is to determine at which string offset column height would be exceeded. I have no idea how to do it except adding text to the column character after character and measure `TextBlock` element to get `DesiredSize`.`Height`. This can be too slow though.

Comment: @Harry Sorry, But I don't clearly understand your point. Don't you want vertical scrolling of text, just fill up a column with text and when done switch to the next column to fill remaining text, like MS News app shipped with Windows 8.1.

Comment: No scrolling at all. All on screen, perfectly readable. Imagine you have wide rectangle. Fixed dimensions. You have text to fit let's say 2 columns. It has to be split to fill first column, and a part of second column. The problem is to determine where should I split the text. At which character. The text is unknown at control creation time. I have to calculate split offset, then I can render columns. Naive algorithm for this is far too slow. Even optimized algorithm would still use `Measure` method a couple of times. I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Well one way i'm thinking would be to create a loop then add it to a textblock using inlines, check this example:

```
    string teststring = "fdssssssfdsfdsfjhjkdhfjkdsjkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkfsdfdsfdscccxcxvdsfsfdsfsdf";

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < teststring.Length; i += 10)
        {
            if ((i + 10) < teststring.Length)
            {
                textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = Environment.NewLine + teststring.Substring(i, 10) });
            }
            else
            {
                textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = Environment.NewLine +  teststring.Substring(i) });
            }
        }
    }
```